# Tfidf of a list of documents

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a list of documents(TDT2 corpus) and I want to get a vocabulary from it using tfidf. Using textblob is taking forever and I don't see it producing a vocabulary before 5-6 days given the speed. Is there any other technique to go about this? I came across scikit-learn's tfidf technique but I am afraid it too will take the same amount of time.

```
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

    results = []
    with open("/Users/mxyz/Documents/wholedata/X_train.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            results.append(line.strip().split('\n'))

    blob=[]
    for line in results:
        blob.append(line)


    count_vect= CountVectorizer()


   counts=count_vect.fit_transform(blob)
   print(counts.shape)
```

This keeps producing an error about not accepting a list and that list does not have lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `results` should just be a `list`, not a `list` of `list`s? If that's the case, change:

```
results.append(line.strip().split('\n'))
```

to:

```
results.extend(line.strip().split('\n'))
```

`append` is adding the whole `list` returned by `split` as a single element in the `results` `list`; `extend` is adding the items from that `list` to `results` individually.

Side-note: As written

```
blob=[]
for line in results:
    blob.append(line)
```

is just doing a shallow copy of `results` the slow way. You can replace that with either `blob = results[:]` or `blob = list(results)` (the latter is slower, but if you didn't know what sort of iterable `results` was and needed it to be a `list` and nothing else, that's how you'd do it).